# Like system with Codeigniter and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my like system an user can give more than 1 like but the system register on the db just one, i think is a problem related to AJAX.

This is the button:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-white" name="btn" onclick="usercountcomments(<?php echo $value['user_id'].",".$value['personal_closest_id'].",".$value['id']; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><span id="countVal1_<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['countcomments']; ?></span> Cool </a>
```

And this one is the jscript AJAX script:

```
function usercountcomments(user_id,postId,id){
var a = $("#countVal1_"+id).text();
var display = document.getElementById("countVal1_"+id);
var count = a;
var user_comments="cool";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>social/commentcool/" +user_id+"/"+postId+"/"+user_comments,
    data:{ user_comments : user_comments},
    success: function(data) { 
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
       // alert(a++);   
    }
});
}
```

What can I do to prevent the user giving more than one like ?

Comment: You'll have to put some sort of check on the server side to ensure that the user hasn't already liked the given comment.

Comment: does your ajax request working?

Comment: The ajax is working, the database is saving just 1 like but i can give more then 1 <?php echo $value['countcomments']; ?> take the value of all the click so if i press 3 times becomes 3, but after a refresh of the page read on database and check is one so become again 1...

Comment: solved adding this in ajax: 
$("#disablecommentcool_"+id).attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookie

```
<?php
$id =$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_COOKIE['like'.$id])) {
    echo "error";
    exit;
}else {
    $sql = "UPDATE post SET likecount=likecount+1 WHERE id=$id";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $sql = "SELECT likecount from post where id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row['likecount'];
        setcookie('like'.$id,true, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can clear the cookies and like post again (to increase count). You need to check for records in database did this particular userID already liked that particular PostID.